# Helper class for Null and Empty checks

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have some static helper class:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static bool IsNull<T>(this T value) where T : class
    {
        return (value == null);
    }

    public static bool NotNull<T>(this T value) where T : class
    {
        return (!value.IsNull<T>());
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }

    public static bool NotNullAndNotEmpty(this string value)
    {
        return (!value.IsNullOrEmpty());
    }

    public static bool NotNullAndNotEmpty(this ICollection value)
    {
        return (value.NotNull<ICollection>() && (value.Count > 0));
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this ICollection value)
    {
        return (!value.NotNullAndNotEmpty());
    }
}
```

It is comfortable (habit) for me to use this helper, but I am not sure that it is correctly (worth it). How about performance? Are there any other reasons to not use it?

Comment: Isn't `IsNullOrEmpty` just replacing the same exact extension?

Comment: I don't see any problems with this code.

Comment: Perf is a non-issue.  Having somebody else read your code and have no clue why it works is an issue.  These extension methods look like instance methods in the code, seeing them being use on null objects is a nasty speed-bump.  That extension methods support a null object is frankly a bit of a bug, not a feature, given that this is so very unlike the way the rest of the language works.  But I'm sure you'll disagree :)

Comment: @Fuji String.IsNullOrEmpty is static. Helper.IsNullOrEmpty can be called as if it was a non-static method.

Comment: @kol and yet, it *is* still a static method, in every sense, really.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yes it is. I just said, it *can be called* as if it was non-static.

Comment: @kol gotcha :-)

Comment: @HansPassant hmm... if I disagreed then I would not ask question. I use some helper, it likes me (call as instance method (I know that it is static still :)), encapsulation in one place (it does not matter for 'e != null', but...), typing faster (for me)). I've used it for 1 year, and would like to know, probably it is 'bad' habit? :D

Comment: I'd call `NotNullAndNotEmpty` `NeitherNullNorEmpty` instead, but that's just me.

Comment: @Maxim Just a note; you don't need to explicitly set the template argument in `NotNullAndNotEmpty` and `NotNull`. `return (!value.IsNullOrEmpty());` and `return (!value.IsNull());` work just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This gets to be a sticky point.  There are those who will argue *fervently* that an extension method should *never* work on a `null` reference, and there are those who are fine with that.

Personally, I don't mind extension methods on `null` *if* the name is a clear indicator that `null` is a possibility (like `IsNullOrEmpty`) but as I said, that's my opinion and may not match others.

Don't worry about the performance, method calls are not a serious impact and check methods like this eliminate some of the readability concerns over compound expressions when maintaining the code.  After all, that's what `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` does, but it does it through a static method instead of an extension method.

So the only concern, really, you may get push back that these are extension methods as opposed to ordinary static methods, but you'll get differing opinions on whether calling an extension method on `null` is bad/okay.

One could argue Microsoft disallows LINQ extension methods on `null` sequences, but then again Microsoft also doesn't disallow extension method calls on a `null` source in general.

So, the choice is yours, I don't have an issue with them since the names clearly indicate `null` is an accepted possibility, but I can see both sides of the argument.

On a side note, I'd keep your naming consistent:

- NotNull -> IsNotNull
- NotNullAndNotEmpty -> IsNotNullAndNotEmpty

Comment: I'd really like to see someone's argument on why it is fundamentally wrong to have an extension method for potentially null values.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: I think the main concern is that extension methods are designed to *look* like instance methods, but in that particular aspect they *differ* from instance methods, thus it *could* be misleading as a maintenance/readability issue.  I'm not saying that's a reason not to do it, but you do get that argument a lot.

Comment: But an instance method can still be called when the object is null. Either way, you get a null reference exception regardless wehether or not it is an instance method or extension method.  Maybe I am not grasping the merits of the argument.

Comment: Welcome :) value.NotNull() extension method cannot be used in Linq2Sql: ...Where(i => (i != null)) => works ok, ...Where(i => i.NotNull()) => occurs run-time exception.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: Not necessarily, there's nothing that says your extension method can't handle `null` (like his does), but an instance method can never handle `null` was my main point.  Also, an extension method should never directly throw a `NullReferenceException`, that's a system exception that only the CLR should throw.  Unless you meant indirectly by dereferencing, then sure!

Comment: I see what you mean.  An instance method would throw a null reference exception by merely calling it on a null object, but an extension method would still execute, but die inside if trying to unconditionally reference the null object passed through.  I still wouldn't argue against it either way, though.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: Oh, I agree, I take a pretty neutral stance on it.  I just prefer that if the method is designed to handle `null`, it at least indicate that with a meaningful name (like `IsNullOrEmpty()`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly what's the win for you with this helper class. Most of the methods you have shown seem like some overhead. For example:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string value) 
{ 
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value); 
}
```

Although it will provide you a fluent syntax in your code. Performance will not bite you, your not doing very heavy things inside your extension methods.

Comment: It can be called as if it was a non-static method: `s.IsNullOrEmpty()`. I guess he prefers this format over `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)`.